# Font awesome icon does not show up when I use it with other css file

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a situation where my `font-awesome` is not working as expected.

I have my style sheet and the one from the `font-awesome`

```
    <head>
        <title> Millionique Square </title>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e9148616db.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
```

If I comment this line:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

It works. How can I fix this issue?

Github Repo: https://github.com/rjain09/formValidation.git

Comment: Check what codes/styles in the `styles.css` is overriding the properties of font awesome icons

Comment: try adding `defer` to the script tag: this will make it run after page load. `<script defer src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e9148616db.js"></script>`

Comment: That didn't work @Jongwoo Lee

Answer (score 0):

You have to load scripts in after `body` not in `head`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Millionique Square </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <!-- Your body content -->
    </body>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e9148616db.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: No, that didn't work. Even font awesome says to add it to the head. 
https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/check-circle

Comment: @SJ9 can you provide your ```styles.css```?

Comment: I have added my css file

Comment: In the GitHub repo

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<head>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d1341f9b7a.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Comment: That's not normal. Where can I see all your code? Do you have a git repository?

Comment: https://github.com/rjain09/formValidation.git
@Gass

Comment: @SJ9 Font Awesome is working. If you don't believe me move for example `<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>` outside the `form-group` div. You don't see them because the `.form-group i` class in your CSS has `visility: hidden;` that is set up like that to work with the JavaScript for form validation.

Comment: @SJ9 great, I would appreciate if you could check the answer..

Answer (score 0):

It’s because you didn’t import your `index.js` script file

So no code added the `success` or `error` class to `form-control` which would override the `visibility`

```css
.form-control i {
    visibility: hidden; /* <- hide the icon*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

[here](https://github.com/rjain09/formValidation/blob/a2b7a28333c182109c1aa7222cc294df6e05e4a5/style.css#L76)

Comment: I imported the Javascript file using this line:
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

However, still, the exclamation mark and circle does not show up.